# Make a view's width at least as big to different view

Tags: android, user-interface

I have two view below each other. The bottom view needs to be at least as big as the top view.

I am able to constrain the bottom view to have same size as the top one, but it probihits the view to have bigger width.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                             xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                             android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                             android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Base textview"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:background="@color/module_color_blue"
        android:id="@+id/textView"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Smaller"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
        android:background="@color/red"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/textView"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

On the other hand I am able to have the bottom view unconstrained, however view can get smaller that the top one.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                             xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                             android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                             android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Base textview"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:background="@color/module_color_blue"
        android:id="@+id/textView"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Much longer that top textview"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
        android:background="@color/red"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/textView"
        />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Can I achieve that with existing layout or do I need special layout for that ?

**Scenario A:**

[image]

The bottom view is smaller that top so they have the same width

**Scenario B:**

[image]

The bottom view is bigger that top its not constrained

Comment: Post your code. I think you want that your views are of similar width and height, in that case you can take a layout and specify the layout width and height, and take your views inside that layout and make it wrap-context. For better suggestion paste your snippet.

Comment: @MelonTherapy, you could try the solution posted here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put both views inside `LinearLayout` and set `LinearLayout` width as `wrap_content` and top view with as `match_parent` and bottom view width as `wrap_content` :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
     <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text1"/>
     <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text2text2"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly then you want to have the same width for both textviews and width picked should be of the larger text. In this case you can use `TableLayout` like below :

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   >

<TextView
    android:text="TextView20938487494590786907809568659"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:background="#80123456"
 />

<TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:background="#80723456"
     />

</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, You could try this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/blue"
        android:text="Base TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:text="Much Longer than top textView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The trick here is to set the parent layout width to a certain width.
Then set the width of the children, i.e the two textView's width equal to the width of the parent layout...

PS: If you wish to center align the text inside, you can set the android:gravity="center_horizontal" in your textViews. Hope this helps.

Comment: If you found it useful, please upvote the answer and mark it correct... :)

Comment: I dont have enough reputation :(

Answer (score 0):

> Take a linear layout and specify your views.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="This is TextView 1"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="This is TextView 1"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

[image]